# signature error while installing cakephp 3 with composer

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I'm using composer to install the latest release of cakephp from the packagist repo. I'm following the exact procedure written in the docs but i'm getting this error.

```js
  [Composer\Repository\RepositorySecurityException]
  The contents of http://packagist.org/p/provider-2013%245eabcb75d94b428ce510270878b2b10a81e00b8afaaf4d5e9896b274ec0fbeaa.json do not match its signature. This should indicate a man-in-the-middle attack. Try running composer again and report this if you think it is a mistake.



create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

[image]

**Note**: I've also tried self updating the composer.phar file but still of no use.

Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: People cannot always see images in Questions. Please copy the text from the image.

Comment: Please post the output of `php composer.phar -vvv create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app bookmarker`, but as text instead of an image.

Comment: Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

A typical reason for the *man-in-the-middle attack* warning is that composer cannot find the packagist repository.

However, in your case, it's probably because you have called

```
php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app bookmarker
```

instead of

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app bookmarker
```

Which is the command you need to run in Windows, as per the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html#getting-cakephp), once you've installed Composer using the [Composer Windows Installer](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe).

Comment: Windows installation may need further steps, as described in the [Composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows).

Comment: I used the above describes procedure few days ago and it worked.. now its not working.

Comment: Have you recently set up a proxy by any chance?